# Print Binary Tree By Tilting Your Head

Tags: java, for-loop, binary-tree, nodes, println

Hello to all once again,

I've been assigned to print my binary tree in a way where we're supposed to turn our head to the left and look at it sideways - It will make sense when I provide an image.

[image: Binary Tree Image]

I don't know if my Insert Method or if my showTree Method is wrong.

Here is my InsertMethod:

```
public void insert(Keyed item)
   {
      _root = insert(_root, item);
   }
   
   private TNode insert (TNode myRoot,Keyed item)
   {
      if(myRoot == null)
      {
         TNode newNode = new TNode();
         newNode.data = item;
         newNode.left = null;
         newNode.right = null;
         return newNode;
      }
      
      int comp = item.KeyComp(myRoot.data);
      
      if(comp < 0)
      {
         myRoot.left = insert(myRoot.left, item);
      }
      else if (comp > 0)
      {
         myRoot.right = insert(myRoot.right, item);
      }
      return myRoot;   
   }
```

Here is my showTree Method:

```
public void showTree()
   {
      showTree(_root,1);  
   }
   
   private void showTree(TNode myRoot,int myLevel)
   {
      if(myRoot == null) 
      {
         return;
      }
      
      for(int i = 0; i < myLevel; i++)
      {
         System.out.print("\t");
         
      }  
      showTree(myRoot.right, myLevel + 1);
      System.out.println(myRoot.data.toStr());
      showTree(myRoot.left, myLevel + 1);      
   }
```

If there are any additional methods needed in order to help - I can submit it, but I honestly don't know if my insert method is not doing something correctly, or if my ShowTree Method is not spacing out my Binary Tree correctly.

I would deeply appreciate some help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try printing the right node before you print the indentations for the current node. Something like this:

```
private void showTree(TNode myRoot,int myLevel)
{
  if(myRoot == null) 
  {
     return;
  }
  
  showTree(myRoot.right, myLevel + 1);
  for(int i = 0; i < myLevel; i++)
  {
     System.out.print("\t");
     
  }
  System.out.println(myRoot.data.toStr());
  showTree(myRoot.left, myLevel + 1);      
}
```

Also I think you should start at level 0, call `showTree(_root,0);`

I personally think it would be more readable if you would combine the indentation to one string and then print it. something like this:

```
private void showTree(TNode myRoot,int myLevel)
{
  if(myRoot == null) 
  {
     return;
  }
  
  String currentNodeIdentation = "";
  for(int i = 0; i < myLevel; i++)
  {
     currentNodeIdentation += "\t";
  }
  
  showTree(myRoot.right, myLevel + 1);
  System.out.println(currentNodeIdentation + myRoot.data.toStr());
  showTree(myRoot.left, myLevel + 1);      
}
```

Or if you have java 11 you can even use `currentNodeIdentation = "\t".repeat(myLevel)`.

Comment: @rockyDodgers No problem. I added a bit of a subjective idea for improving the code to the answer, maybe it makes it more readable :)